# Spring Security only lets one user connected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring Boot application and I can't get the security working. I have a customized user class, which instances are saved in a data base.

**When a first user logs in, everything works perfectly, but when a second one logs in, this second user replaces the first one in all connected devices**. I have tested it locally and in an installation at Pivotal Cloud Foundry, with the same result.

This is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
}

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{}
}
```

This is the UserService implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
RoleRepository roleRepository;            

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    RentalWebsUser userInfo = userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roleRepository.getRolesByUsername(username);

    if(userInfo != null && !authorities.isEmpty()){
        User user = new User(userInfo.getUsername(), userInfo.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);

        RentalWebsUser userDetails = new RentalWebsUser(user, userInfo.getIdweb(), userInfo.getName(), userInfo.getSurname());

        return userDetails;

    } else throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong user/password");
}

}
```

This is the AuthenticationProvider implementation:

```
@Component
public class RwAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

RentalWebsUser userDetails;

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userService;

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    User user = null;
    Authentication auth =  null;
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        userDetails = (RentalWebsUser) userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if(userDetails != null){
            user = userDetails.getUser();
        } else throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong user/password");

    if(password == null || !password.equals(user.getPassword())) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong user/password");

    if(user != null){
        auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    } else throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong user/password");

    return auth;
}

public RentalWebsUser getUserDetails(){
    return userDetails;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
    return true;
}

}
```

An this is an extract of the configuration, but it is important to remark, that the system behaves in the same way without it:

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer  extends    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{SecurityConfig.class};
}
```

Finally, I get the principal from a PostgreSQL DB with an instance of `RentalWebsUser`:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

@Override
public RentalWebsUser getUserByUsername(String username){
    String SQL = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username";
    SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource("username", username);

    RentalWebsUser user = (RentalWebsUser) namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, param, new UserMapper());

    return user;
}

private static final class UserMapper implements RowMapper {

    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {

        RentalWebsUser user = new RentalWebsUser();

        user.setIdweb(rs.getInt("idweb"));
        user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        user.setEnabled(rs.getBoolean("enabled"));
        user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        user.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
        user.setIdcountry(rs.getInt("idcountry"));

        return user;

    }

}
```

}

I have spend hours reading the Spring documentation and tutorials, without being able to find any solution, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the `RentalWebsUser` an instance variable of the `AuthenticationProvider`? This detail might lead to the described behaviour!

Comment: It's definitely a bug, but there must be something else too

Comment: @fateddy `RentalWebsUser` is an implementation of `UserDetails` where I keep a few values, that I need across the whole application. To get them from the AuthenticationProvider implementation, probably doesn't make sense, but when I wrote it I was a complete beginner with Spring. Would it be better to get them from the `UserDetailsService` implementation or I should create a new class?

Comment: How do you retrieve the info of the current principal? Is this a spring-managed bean - and if - what scope? (could you add the relevant code as well?)

Comment: @fateddy you made me realize that I didn't consider the scope at all. **Setting a session scope at the `AuthenticationProvider` implementation has worked out**. I've added an answer explaining it, and at the end of the original post, I've added the code of the @Repository class, with which I get the principal from a PostgreSQL DB. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom [`AuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html)-implementation is not needed in this case. The available Spring-Security components should be sufficient. I would strongly recommend to stick with these components.
Besides that, the current implementation looks a "broken" (eg. why is the UserDetails-Model actually a Sevice??).

Let's try to fix the things...

(Mis-)Using the `AuthenticationProvider` (which is a [Singleton](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-singleton) Instance) as an Authentication-Holder was the reason, why the last successful login showed up. That is why a singleton instance basically shouldn't keep state.

The important thing to know is how to access the currently logged in user: Spring-Security stores an [`Authentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object into the [`SecurityContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html). It can be accessed like this (eg. in your Handler-method):

```
 import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

 ...
 @Controller
 class SiteController {

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    String adminArea() {
       Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       MyUser principal = (MyUser) auth.getPrincipal();
       // The object-type is the same that is returned by the `UserDetailsService#loadUserByName()` implementation
       String username = user.getUsername();
       ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively there is a convenient way to inject the currently logged in User into a Handler-Method like this (see [@AuthenticationPrincipal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal) for details):

```
@Controller
class SiteController {

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    String admin(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUser user, Model model) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        MyUser principal = (MyUser) auth.getPrincipal();
        // `user` and `principal` is referencing the same object!
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("principal", principal);
        ...
    }
}
```

## A working example

Lets see the components needed to get a working example.

### The Security-Config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
            .rememberMe();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

### The UserDetailsService

```
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private MyUserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(MyUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        MyUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            // if user already implements the `UserDetails`-interface, the object could be directly returned
            // if not, wrap it into a pojo fulfilling the `UserDetails`-contract - eg.
            // return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            return user;
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " could not be found");
    }
}
```

### The Login Controller and Form

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    String loginForm() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

*resources/templates/login.html* (thymeleaf)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also take a look at the getting-started series: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Answer (score 0):

@fateddy has made me realize that I didn't consider **the scope** at all, and that **was the key to solve the issue**.

In the way I have set Spring Security, the implementation of the `AuthenticationProvider`, seems to be the starting point of the login process. Setting there a **Session Scope** has worked out:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RwAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {...
```

I have the user details in the `UserDetailsService` implementation with its roles, and at the `AuthenticationProvider` implementation (`RwAuthenticationProvider`), from where I retrieve them to set them at a Controller Model, with with this class:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsModel {
Integer idproperty;
Integer idweb;

@Autowired
private RwAuthenticationProvider userDetails;

@Autowired
private PropertyRepository propertyRepository;

//Navigation bar - adminTmplt.htnl
public Model getUserDetailsModel(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("userName", userDetails.getUserDetails().getName());
    model.addAttribute("surname", userDetails.getUserDetails().getSurname());
    model.addAttribute("email", userDetails.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("property", userDetails.getUserDetails().getPropertyName());
    model.addAttribute("idproperty", getIdProperty());

    return model;
}

public Integer getIdProperty(){
    idproperty = userDetails.getUserDetails().getIdproperty();
    return idproperty;
}

public Integer getIdWeb(){
    idweb = userDetails.getUserDetails().getIdweb();
    return idweb;
}

public String getPropertyName(){
    String propertyName = userDetails.getUserDetails().getPropertyName();

    return propertyName;
}

public void setIdproperty(Integer idproperty){
    userDetails.getUserDetails().setIdproperty(idproperty);
    String propertyName = propertyRepository.getPropertyById(idproperty).getName();
    userDetails.getUserDetails().setPropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

That's the customized implementation of `UserDetails`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class RentalWebsUser implements UserDetails, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idweb")
private Integer idweb;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

//Not persistent
private int idproperty;
private String propertyName;
private User user;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "idcountry")
private int idcountry;

//private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public RentalWebsUser(){}

public RentalWebsUser(User user, int idweb, String name, String surname) {
    this.idweb = idweb;        
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.user = user;
} 

...Getters and Setters

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return this.user.isAccountNonExpired();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return this.user.isAccountNonLocked();
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
     return this.user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

...hashCode, equals and toString methods omitted.
```

I fear that my settings are not accurate enough, therefore any recommendation to improve them will be more than welcome.

Thanks a lot, once more to all you.

Comment: The `AuthenticationProvider` should be stateless. Could it be that you retrieve the currently logged in user from `RwAuthenticationProvider#getUserDetails()`? Could you add the relevant code that shows how you retrieve the currently logged in User?

Comment: @fateddy I retrieve the user details, with a class that I have added to my answer, to set them into a controller from `RwAuthenticationProvider`with the method `getUserDetails`
I fear I have misunderstood the  `AuthenticationProvider` implementation.
I haven't investigated it yet, but the remember-me functionality doesn't work, maybe it has something to do with this issue.

Comment: There are some bits - although working right now - broken. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue happens when you log in with a different user WITHOUT logging out first.

If this is the case then it happens because the actual session is not renewed after the successful login. This should be done by an eventListener what is called by the AuthenticationManager if it was set up properly.

I think we have 2 AuthenticationManagers here - one is set up properly by the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and an other one what is created by the builder what is passed to the `configureGlobalSecurity` method and actually is in use later.

I had a similar issue a long time ago.

Try the following:

Add the following line into the `configuration` method:

```
http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
```

Comment out the `configureGlobalSecurity` method

Oh, one more thing: Try to extend the DaoAuthenticationProvider instead of creating your own. You will thank it later...

Comment: In fact, the issue happens, when connecting to the app from different devices, or different browsers in the same machine. All open sessions with different IDs, adopt the user of the last one connected.

I have tried commenting out the  `configureGlobalSecurity`, to prevent 2 AuthenticationManagers, as you suggest, but unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: In this case I think the bug is not in the code you inserted here. There must be something else somewhere else...